# Temperature in 40s or in the 40s?

Tags: phrase-usage, articles

In the temperature forecast, 40s means 40 ~ 49 degrees.

However, I have seen both **in 40s** and **in *the* 40s**. Which one is correct, or both? And any reason if there is?

[image]

Comment: In the US, it's almost always, "in the 40s". Perhaps this is a regionalism?

Comment: I just added what I searched on Yahoo.

Comment: You shouldn't use headlines to learn English: _Words often omitted in headlines for brevity_.

Comment: The most recent topic on headlines: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151159/why-no-verb-in-passive-voice-phrase/151161#151161

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why no verb in passive voice phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151159/why-no-verb-in-passive-voice-phrase)

Answer (score 1):

You should never use news headlines as examples of grammar, as they are nearly always abbreviated.

We would say "temperatures *in the 40s*" because 'the 40s' is a group or range.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that grammatically, it would 40s.  Adding the "," to it, would make it a possessive, using the decade of the years 40-49 as a noun. Example: 1940's fashions included the infamous "zoot suit".

I taught middle school grammar for a good number of years, and would think that good number of fellow teachers would be in agreement.

Comment: Did you mean to say '(apostrophe) instead of ,(comma)?